# Redux state variable is showing up as undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am making an application using React and redux. I am working to achieve the funcionaity where the "main-page" checks for auth, and if auth is "false" , it redirects to the "auth-page". This is how I am trying to achieve the said functionality.

index.js

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import "./css/index.css";
import AppScreen from "./screens/appscreen";
import NotFoundScreen from "./screens/notfoundscreen";
import AuthScreen from "./screens/authscreen";

import isLoggedInReducer from "./redux/reducers/isLoggedInReducer";

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={createStore(isLoggedInReducer,window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() )}>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact>
            <AppScreen />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/auth">
            <AuthScreen />
          </Route>
          <Route path="*">
            <NotFoundScreen />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

isLoggedIn reducer

```js
const isLoggedInReducer = (isLoggedIn = true , action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'LOG_IN':
            return true
        case 'LOG_OUT':
            return false
        default:
            return false
    }
}

export default isLoggedInReducer
```

main-app

```js
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Redirect } from "react-router";

import BottomBar from "../components/bottombar";
import Content from "../components/content";
import NavBar from "../components/navbar";

import "../css/screens/appscreen.css";

const AppScreen = () => {
  let isLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => {
    console.log(state)
    return state
  });
  // the value isLoggedIn is undefined here
  return isLoggedIn ? (
    <>
      <div className="appscreen">
        <NavBar />
        <Content />
        <BottomBar />
      </div>
    </>
  ) : (
    <>
      <Redirect to="/auth" push />
    </>
  );
};

export default AppScreen;
```

I tried to read the value from the store using the useSelector hook.But the variable is undefined. It does not show up in the redux dev tools, it doesnt exist nowhere. I am currently only trying to read the value from the variable
I would like to add I currently am not trying to change the value of the variable right now.

This is my first time with redux, and its already a bit confusing to wrap head around so much boilerplate code. I do thank you for your time !

Comment: try making isLoggedIn const,instead of let

Comment: that did nothing :(

Comment: dont loose hope! first check if isLoggedIn is getting updated or not,check it this way:
useEffect(()=>{console.log(isLoggedIn)},[isLoggedIn]);

Comment: I did uncover something strange. apparantly, its the default case of the reducer that returns the value. if I type " return 'hello world' " , I am getting that in the console.log. But the isLoggedIn variable itself doesnt appear in the redux devtools, nowhere.

Comment: after using useEffect, I get errors saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'isLoggedIn' before initialization"

Comment: may be this can work(assuming you want isLoggedIn value on the first render):
const[isLoggedIn,setIsLoggedIn]=useState();
useEffect(()=>{const val=useSelector((state) => {
    
    return state
  });setIsLoggedIn(val)},[]); 
....rest of the code...

Comment: Try retuning the ```isLoggedIn``` state, not just ```false``` and see what you get :)

Comment: I need to handle state management using redux, thats part of the problem. I understand for a single variable, useState is plenty but I got a big state. I just tested the first variable and it didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the problem is in isLoggedInReducer function, you should understand Reducers, Reducers are functions that take the current state and an action as arguments, and return a new state result. In other words, (state, action) => newState. so you should defined an initialState and passe it to isLoggedInReducer function like that :

The state parameter that gets passed to the reducer function has to be the current state of the application. In this case, we’re calling that our initialState because it will be the first (and current) state and nothing will precede it.

```
const initialState = { isLoggedIn : true };
const isLoggedInReducer = (state = initialState , action) => {
switch(action.type){
    case 'LOG_IN':
        return {...state ,  isLoggedIn : true };
    case 'LOG_OUT':
        return { ...state , isLoggedIn : false };
    default:
        return state;
  }
}

export default isLoggedInReducer;
```

you can check this Link for more infos about Reducer : https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#writing-reducers

Comment: I made the necessary changes and the state is showing. Thank you. Also, please do tell, if any component makes use of useSelector on a piece of state, will the component re-render if the state is changed ?

Comment: I have got a new issue where the variable is being changed in the state but the component where I used "useSelector" does not re-render when the variable changes

Comment: useSelector() uses strict === reference equality checks by default, not shallow equality. so we must create a new reference of state, i update my sugest solution check it